# Bootstrap-Datepicker in modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-9, bootstrap-datepicker

When the bootstrap-datepicker is used inside a modal window, there is no decoration on hover events (days, buttons...) and current date is not highlighted.

It works fine when the datepicker is not inside a modal window.

How can I fix that?

[image: No decoration]

Edit :

in my view "Details.cshtml":

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImpactForm.DateFinTestPilote, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
<div class="col-md-8">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImpactForm.DateFinTestPilote)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImpactForm.DateDebutTestPilote)
</div>
</div>
```

I have an editor template for Nullable DateTime type :

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.Nullable<DateTime>>
@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Html.TextBox("", (Model.Value.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", null, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
}
```

bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js are loaded in _Layout.cshtml.

datepicker.css, bootstrap-datepicker.js and bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js are loaded in Details.cshtml

Comment: you are opening a complete view in model or partial view

Comment: It is an ASP.NET MVC4 view (called with the @RenderBody)

Comment: try loading css of bootstrap in the view itself not in layout  which you are opening in model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Loading CSS of Bootstrap in View itself and not in Layout,i think in your problem other CSS's is modifying css of bootstrap so load css of bootstrap in view where you are opening the modal.

Thanks!!